# Load the view user was at

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my CodeIgniter based website, my sidebar has the login box.

In the login controller, I have the following code:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view('loginfail');
        }           
        else
        {
            $this->load->view('loginsuccess');
        }
```

Currently, in case of a failed login, it redirects to loginfail view.

What I want to do is send the user back to the view he was at. But since the login box is in a sidebar which is loaded onto every other view, how can I know which view the user was at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try passing it the output of [current_url()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html), which returns the segments of the URI currently viewed; it's a function of the URL helper.

As you suggested, you could place it inside a hidden input field and retrieve the value in the controller/library which handles the authentication.

Comment: Hmm, seems like current_url() would do the trick for me. I'll give it a shot

Comment: it seems current_url if placed in a controller returns the name of the controller. But I could use current_url and pass it has a hidden form variable along with the post data.

Comment: yeah, passing the referrer page as a hidden field worked. Thanks for the tip about current_url()

Comment: @xbonez you're right, I didn't think about it. I corrected my answer, sorry